# JNativeHook through build.gradle can't be found

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I wanted to ask for your help on importing JNativeHook through build.gradle for my Java project.

The build.gradle seems to build, but the library can't be found in my project.

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.github.kwhat:jnativehook:2.2.1'
}

mainClassName = "lt.vu.cs.softwaredesign.Main"

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'lt.vu.cs.softwaredesign.Launcher'
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    destinationDirectory = file("$rootDir/out")
    // change the assignment number in filename of the jar
    archiveFileName = "assignment1.jar"
}
```

I get "error: package com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.keyboard is not visible

import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;
^

(package com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.keyboard is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.keyboard does not read it)
^                 "

I have a module-info.java for such occasions, but that doesn't seem to help.

module-info.java:

```
module lt.vu.cs.softwaredesign { 
exports lt.vu.cs.softwaredesign; 
requires com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener; 
}
```